# How to read a cx_Oracle.OBJECT with type cx_Oracle.ObjectType SYS.XMLTYPE?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying read the content of a `XMLType` column from Oracle with cx_Oracle but i don't get it.

```
>>> row
(318, 379, 1, <cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0xef21ea0>)
>>> col = row[3]
>>> print col
<cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0xef21ea0>
>>> print col.type
<cx_Oracle.ObjectType SYS.XMLTYPE>
```

How can I read the content of a `cx_Oracle.OBJECT` with type `cx_Oracle.ObjectType SYS.XMLTYPE`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? I'm not familiar with cx_Oracle. But from pure OCI API point of view Oracle's support for XML is quite schizophrenic. If you want to deal with the datatype `SYS.XMLTYPE` as it was "real" XML you must use a library named `libxml.a` (together with OCI driver lib: `libclnt.so`). This library `libxml.a` is NOT included in InstantClient and even is NOT part of the Oracle XE server installation. You probably should download and install the full "thick" Oracle client and then compile this cx_Oracle driver with this  full client.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, @Ivan. I think this is exactly the problem. So, I prefered to use this (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/mastering-oracle-python-xml-1391344.html) solution [using "select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('%s') from dual"] than compile a specific version  of InstantClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in Ivan's comment, a solution is compile a cx_Oracle with `libxml.a`. As workaround, I used the solution proposed in the following page and read all the content as XML.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/mastering-oracle-python-xml-1391344.html