# How to read a cx_Oracle.OBJECT with type cx_Oracle.ObjectType SYS.XMLTYPE in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I connected to oracle database and fetched some of the columns from the table.
It gave one of the column as `cx_Oracle.OBJECT` with type `<cx_Oracle.ObjectType SYS.XMLTYPE>`.

I need to read the XML Data in this and validate.

I have idea that [XML Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html) is there in robot framework, to parse the Object, it is not accepting `cx_Oracle.OBJECT`,  how to read `cx_Oracle.OBJECT` of type `<cx_Oracle.ObjectType SYS.XMLTYPE>`.

My Robot Framework Testcase is as below:

Query From CB_ADDRESS_XML

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    cx_Oracle    '${Username}/${Password}@${Host}:${Port}/${DatabaseName}'

${result}=    Query    select address_x from cb_address_xml where ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N='21818'

Log    ${result[0][0]}

Disconnect From Database
```

Output came as :

```
INFO : ${result} = [(<cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x032AE700>,), (<cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x032AE720>,), (<cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x032AE740>,)]

INFO : <cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x032AE700>
```

`<cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x032AE700>` is a xml object, i want to read this and validate the values in xml.

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: how does "Log  <fetched columns>" look like?

Comment: output from the cx_oracle came as `${result} = [(<cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x0307CF80>,), (<cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x0307CFA0>,), (<cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x0307CFC0>,)]`

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904684/how-to-read-a-cx-oracle-object-with-type-cx-oracle-objecttype-sys-xmltype ? As per this, the issue is with the installation of Cx_Oracle without libxml . The problem is in the way records are sent by Oracle, so nothing to do on robotframework end I suppose.

Comment: As per that we need to install think Oracle client and that question is about, we need to write python code, i want to know any way is there through robot framework, without writing custom python library code. To install thick oracle client, i am not sure what my IT Support team in company will tell, thick oracle client cann't be the solution because whoever want to use this testcase, need to install thick oracle client first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be implemented as a python keyword and used in Robot framework.

When you implement execute query in python call as below:

```
cursor.execute("select XMLType.GetClobVal(address_x) from cb_address_xml where ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N='21818'")
```

Once you receive the result it will be of type cx_Oracle.LOB, so you can use the below to read its contents:

```
result[column_number].read()
```

This will return XML data which you are looking for.

NOTE: This should be done before you close the DB connection.

Good Luck!